# OpenTok fragment Video publishing with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, opentok

I'm trying to implement video streaming with OpenTok video streaming solution, based on MvvmCross architecture (Android app).

My video page is a MvxFragment, that is instantiated from MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity. That activity manages a couple of fragments, and on custom command it shows my video fragment.

The problem is that i receive video and audio from subscriber, but unable to send the publisher data. Publisher view always shows black screen.

Here is my publisher creation block:

```
public void OnConnected(Session p0)
{
    if (_publisher != null)
        return;

    _publisher = new Publisher(Activity, "publisher", true, true);
    _publisher.SetPublisherListener(this);
    AttachPublisherView(_publisher);
    p0.Publish(_publisher);
}
```

But if i am not using mvvmcross, and implement OpenTok interfaces in FragmentActivity, instead of fragment, everything works fine.

I suppose that, the problem somehow depends on the provided context when i create Publisher, but cannot find the way to get it work.

Will be thankfull to any thoughts or help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found what caused the problem. It was incompatible target android version. After i set it to "Use compile using SDK version" the problem is gone.